# Unit Testing the view of an Angular-UI modal

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, bootstrap-modal

I've recently learned a lot about testing controllers w/ modals, modal controllers and directives. Almost everything in my app that can be tested, is being tested and it's all rainbows and kittens.

My latest (seemingly impossible) problem is that the modal I'm testing has a sort of "wizard" UI, where the user progresses through each step to create something to submit when the modal is closed. I'd like to test that the UI is reacting accordingly.

For example, in the modal controller, when $scope.cloneType is false, I'd like to make sure that my div#cloneMenu is actually showing (or hidden when cloneType has been set).

In a directive, I can do something like this:

```
$el.isolateScope().cloneType = null;
$scope.$digest();
expect($el.find('#cloneMenu').hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(false);

$el.isolateScope().cloneType = 'basic';
$scope.$digest();
expect($el.find('#cloneMenu').hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);
```

but I don't have $el (or anything like it) available in the modal controller (that I know of). I tried using $document.find() but that didn't work. I'm suspecting that $compile comes in to play at some point, but don't know where.

So, aside from just making the body of my modal a directive and unit testing that, is there any way of testing the DOM in the view of an AngularUI modal dialog? Any code samples or links to info that can help would be appreciated.

I'm using Angular 1.2.9 and Jasmine 2.0 and I've included jQuery so that I have a better find() method. (Being limited to tagName is lame when trying to test/traverse *real* DOM).

Thanks!

Comment: To me, the use case you described sounds like you might be testing some functionality of AngularJS -- not your app. What I mean is that your app's logic sets a variable to false. And now I assume that something in your view uses this boolean value (ng-show, ng-if, etc) to somehow manipulate the DOM. I generally write tests for the code that sets the boolean value to true/false. I avoid testing that `ng-show` (or whatever) that uses the boolean value is showing/hiding the DOM element. You might want to show the appropriate code for the modal view so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Also, one of the paradigms in Angular is that controllers should not do DOM manipulation. I know you're not doing that here... And since controller's shouldn't know about the DOM, then it seem logical that you shouldn't write tests that try to verify things in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, you make some interesting points. I can see what you mean about testing Angular. I guess I was trying to take a similar approach to what I learned about testing the template of a directive being rendered correctly; now I'm wondering if that was the right thing to do. In either case my controllers don't have any knowledge of the DOM, but I don't see why the tests for them shouldn't. I guess with normal controllers, it's just a matter of verifying the model is correct and then visually inspecting the UI/markup that the model is used correctly. Is there no code way to test a view?

Comment: Testing directives that way is absolutely the right thing to do... Directives modify the DOM, so asserting that they add a class/element/etc is perfectly fine. I understand your concern about controllers and their effect on the DOM, and the desire to verify it. That sort of testing probably is more suited to an E2E test using Protractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide an answer just so this question has the conclusion that I was after.

I think Sunil D. has it right with testing the views via an E2E test.

I was forcing myself to see the modal as a 'component' like a directive and so wanted to write tests in that way. I know it's not a directive, but it just felt more natural to test it that way because of how it works/looks/is similar to a directive (controller fn + template).

The other issue was that the controller for this thing is so small (because angular is so awesome) so there was only a couple of tests. I felt there should be more to it and wasn't getting the sense of completeness/accomplishment that I did from writing directive tests.

In the end, I'm just going to finish the tests for the modal controller and look into getting some E2E in the mix. That was next on my list anyway.